# Dependent dropdown is not working in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown, jquery-select2

How to add id in select2 dropdownlist kartik. The goal I want when I choose value "success" in dropdown, so value in the other dropdownlist example2 and example3 disabled is false. Before it, for dropdownlist example2 and example3 with value "yes" is false.

I've created code JavaScript but it is not working. What can I try next?

This my code :

```html
<?php 
echo $form->field($model, 'example')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'model' => $model,
    'hideSearch' => true,
    'data' => ['success' => 'Success', 'fail' => "Fail"],
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Pilih',
        'options' => [
            ['id' => 'example'],
        ]
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'width' => '350px',
        ],
    ])->label('Example'); 
?>

<?php 
echo $form->field($model, 'example2')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'model' => $model,
    'hideSearch' => true,
    'data' => ['yes' => "Yes", 'no' => "No"],
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Pilih',
        'options' => [
            'yes' => ['disabled' => true],
            ['id' => 'example2'],
        ]
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'width' => '350px',
        ],
    ])->label('Example 2'); 
?>

<?php 
echo $form->field($model, 'example3')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'model' => $model,
    'hideSearch' => true,
    'data' => ['yes' => "Yes", 'no' => "No"],
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Pilih',
        'options' => [
            'yes' => ['disabled' => true],
            ['id' => 'example3'],
        ]
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'width' => '350px',
        ],
    ])->label('Example 3'); 
?>
```

This JavaScript code :

```html
<?php
$this->registerJs(' 
$("input[type=dropdown]").change(function() {

    var isi = this.value; 
    if(isi == "success") {
        $("#example2").attr("disabled",false);
        $("#example3").attr("disabled",false);
    } 

});
') 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Provide example of how you would like this to be made.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want.
Add option to first select element (#example):

```
'pluginEvents' => [
        "change" => "function() { 
            var value = $(this).val();
            if(value == 'success') 
            {
                $('#demo-example2').val('yes');
                $('#demo-example2').trigger('change');
                $('#demo-example3').val('yes');
                $('#demo-example3').trigger('change');
            }
        }",    
    ]
```

Comment: Where the placement of the code ? I've tried for put in dropdown with id "example", and the result is fail.

Comment: below _'pluginOptions'_ in the example field.

Comment: Still can not @Wilson Ng

Comment: what is still cannot?